# Missing return statement for money calculation java

Tags: java

It says I am missing a return statement and cant figure out what needs to be returned. Any help would be appreciated, with detailed info, this is my first java program for my CSC200 course!

```
Money.java:23: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error
```

My code:

```
public class Money
{
    // declare class variables
    double total; // used to store the Money value as a double precision floating point number like 34.2
    // you will need more variables declared here to handle each of the currency types; for example int hundreds to keep track of how many hundred dollar bills
    int hundreds;
    // this one will help you print floating point values in US currency format like $10.50
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

    // convert current currency values to a string
    public String toString()
    {

    }

    // converts amount to US currency format
    public String toCurrency(double amount)
    {
      return nf.format(Math.round(amount * 100.0) / 100.0);
    }

    // convert currency to float
    // read currency values from Scanner s and compute value
    // output results
    public void processChange(Scanner s)
    {
    }
```

The full error:
[image]

Comment: Method `String toString()` must - as per definition in the signature - return a `String`. Not returning anything results in the compilation error shown.

Comment: @Turing85 nit: completing normally without returning anything results in a compilation error. You could throw, or have a probably infinite loop such as `while (true);`, and not need a return.

Answer (score -1):

Your method `toString` is empty, but it declares it returns an object of type `String`

```
    public String toString()
    {

    }
```

You can use this method to return a message about the current state of `Money` object. In this case I'd recommend to fill this method with this line:

```
    return "total: " + total + ", hundreds: " + hundreds;
```

If you try to output this object for example using  `System.out.println(...);` you will get the info about each value this object contains.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike your `void processChange()` method, your `String tostring()` method requires a `String` for return values, but the method does not have a return statement.
If you write anything for return, for example,

```
public String toString(){
   return total + hundreds + "";//return a String
}
```

Alternately, if you do not need to execute this method, you can just throw an exception.

```
public String toString(){
   throw new NotSupportedException();//the method is not supported
}
```

If you really need a `toString()` method without returning different strings for different values of `total` and `hundreds`, declare them using the `transient` keyword:

```
transient double total;//will not be serialised.
transient int hundreds;//will not be serialised.

public String toString(){
   return "";//return an empty String
}
```